# How to reset Apple Mail on macOS Mojave without deleting and adding back Internet account?

Tags: macos, mail.app, messages, mojave

I'd like for Apple Mail to start fresh and download and index all of my emails from scratch across multiple email accounts. I read that I might be able to go into internet accounts and delete all of them, and re-add them, but I want to avoid this as this will delete all my Messages history under those accounts, and other app settings associated with these accounts.

Instead, I assume there are a few folders that I can simply go in and delete and when Mail starts up again, it forces a full mailbox rebuild on those accounts, without me having to setup the accounts again and without losing my Messages history and other account settings.

Does anyone know what the procedure is to do this?

Comment: Is the `Mailbox` -> Rebuild helpful for you? As far as I know, it deletes all the attachments and downloads them again.